# Adding space around figures in RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to add space around figures in RMarkdown. I am knitting to PDF and really don't like how close figures (or also equations) are to the text or to the next figure.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

There is just too little space between the two plots and this gets more fuzzy when using ggplots.

Right now I use the Latex solution

```
\vspace{10pt}
```

but it would be nice if I could make a setting globally for the entire document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concerning the spacing before and after plots you can use a simple knitr hook:

````
```{r, echo = F}
library(knitr)
if(is_latex_output()) {
  plot_default <- knit_hooks$get("plot")
  knit_hooks$set(plot = function(x, options) { 
    x <- c(plot_default(x, options), "\\vspace{25pt}")
  })
}
```
````

Here we alter the plot hook in that sense that we just add a spacing of `25pt` after each plot output.

Concerning equations you can just add these four length definitions at the beginning of your document:

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{25pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{25pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{25pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{25pt}
```

The first two alter equations created using the `align` environment. The latter two those created using `$$ ... $$`.

Comment: It will be better to condition this on `knitr::is_latex_output()` (i.e. do not modify the `plot` hook when the output format is not LaTeX).

Comment: @YihuiXie: your point is very valid, but I don't get how to do it. Including the condition gives me "'is_latex_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'".

Comment: Exactly! [When in doubt, upgrade.](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/)

Comment: I stumbled upon this and the knitr hook works perfectly in the next code chunk within the rmd document, but subsequent code chunks produces figures that are once again too close?  I tried copying the code into later chucks but then it fails with the following error "Error: C stack usage  7972320 is too close to the limit
Execution halted"

Comment: @ChuckP I can confirm your observation. I also don't know what's going on but I worked around it by naming the `plot_default` variable different in every chunk, like `plot_default2`, `plot_default3` and so on... I know it's not pretty but I don't have time to spend another few hours on researching what the heck is going on...

Comment: @ChuckP the solution to our problem is to wrap above code in `local({ ... })` as described here https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/output-hooks.html