# How to systematically change knitr \label{} behavior to add hyperlink anchors

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pdflatex, hyperref

I want to change `knitr`'s behavior when it creates a `figure` environment in `LaTeX` to call a different `LaTeX` command than `\label{}`, e.g, `\alabel{}` where I define `\alabel` to run `\label{foo}` as well as `\hypertarget{foo}{}` using the `hyperref` `LaTeX` package.  I'm doing this so that I can construct a URL in a web browser to get to a specific place in the `.pdf` document built with `pdflatex`, e.g. `http://.../my.pdf#nameddest=foo`.

How can I either override `\label{}` or emit an additional `\hypertarget{same label used by \label{}` in the figures?

This is in the context of a `.Rnw` file.  I'd like the anchor to appear inside the `figure` environment`for optimal positioning of the cursor when jumping into the`.pdf` document.

**UPDATE**

In rethinking this I think it's best not to generate `hypertarget` anchors but to write an `R` function that parses the `LaTeX` `aux` file to retrieve the page number of the reference (`\newlabel` lines) to generate the needed URL to the `pdf` file.  In the `.Rnw` or `.Rmd` file I can call this function from within a sentence to insert the computed URL.

**UPDATE**

I've decided after all to go with @werner's excellent method, which works flawlessly.  For anyone interested in the `R`-based approach that doesn't require the use of `hypertarget`, here is the `LaTeX` code needed to set up for it - this handles the case where physical page numbers do not match logical page numbers (e.g., using logical numbers such as chapter number - page within chapter.

```
% Creates .pag file mapping absolute page numbers to logical page
% numbers; works with R function latexRef

\newwrite\pgfile
\immediate\openout\pgfile=\jobname .pag
\newcounter{abspage}
\setcounter{abspage}{0}

\useackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \addtocounter{abspage}{1}
  \immediate\write\pgfile{\thepage, \theabspage}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\immediate\closeout\pgfile}
```

Here's the `R` function that does the lookups in the `.aux, .pag` files:

```
## Create hyperlink to appropriate physical page in a pdf document
## created by pdflatex given the .aux and .pag file.  Absolute and
## named page numbers are store in the .pag file created by hslide.sty

latexRef <- function(label, base, name, path='doc/',
                     blogpath='/home/harrelfe/R/blog/blogdown/static/doc/',
                     lang=c('markdown', 'latex')) {
  lang <- match.arg(lang)
  aux <- paste0(blogpath, base, '.aux')
  if(! file.exists(aux))
    stop(paste('no file named', aux))
  path <- paste0(path, base, '.pdf')
  pag  <- paste0(blogpath, base, '.pag')
  pagemap <- NULL
  if(file.exists(pag)) {
    p <- read.table(pag, sep=',')
    pagemap        <- trimws(p[[2]])
    names(pagemap) <- trimws(p[[1]])
  }

  r <- readLines(aux)
  w <- paste0('\\\\newlabel\\{', label, '\\}')
  i <- grepl(w, r)
  if(! any(i)) stop(paste('no label =', label))
  r <- r[i][1]
  r <- gsub('\\{', ',', r)
  r <- gsub('\\}', ',', r)
  x <- scan(text=r, sep=',', what=character(0), quiet=TRUE)
  section <- x[5]
  if(section != '') section <- paste0(' Section ', section)
  page    <- trimws(x[7])
  if(length(pagemap)) page <- pagemap[page]
  url     <- paste0('http://fharrell.com/', path, '#page=', page)
  switch(lang,
         markdown = paste0('[', name, section, '](', url, ')'),
         latex    = paste0('\\href{', url, '}{', name, section, '}')
         )
  }
```

Comment: Close voter: This question is about the R package `knitr` (on topic), not about LaTeX.

Comment: I think you'll have to modify `hook_plot_tex`, in particular the way how `fig2` is constructed. See [`hooks-latex.R`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/7386aa3960e8126f8accaa35341b578b7af44277/R/hooks-latex.R). Sorry, I don't have the time to fiddle with this right now, but I wish you good luck.

Comment: Does the `\alabel` have to be inside the `figure` environment? If not, editing  the plot hook like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48321490/1777111 could help.

Comment: I guess the answer would be different depending on whether you are using Rnw or R Markdown documents. Either way, it will be great if you can provide a minimal example. (To close voters: [can't you just wait for a second?](https://yihui.name/en/2017/12/so-bounties/))

Comment: I clarified the Rnw context and wish to be inside `figure` environment.  I'm not clear on votes to close - I tried to be honest in my tags.  `LaTeX` users may wish to find this someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following to your LaTeX preamble a global replacement of `\label` with a combination of `\label`-and-`\hypertarget` in the following way:

```latex
---
title: 'A title'
author: 'An author'
date: 'A date'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginDocument{
      \let\oldlabel\label
      \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\oldlabel{#1}\hypertarget{#1}{}}
    }
---

See Figure \ref{fig:figure}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure caption}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I tried a slight variation of that with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351 using the `letltxmacro` package but `pdflatex` ignored it.  I wonder if there is something special about `label`.  But I'm going with the method in the Update to the original question, I think.  Thanks.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: `\label` is *sensitive*, specifically because you're also using [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). That's why I used `\AtBeginDocument` in order to delay the redefinition until the document actually starts.

Comment: Got it.  Great to know that.